# What is the most common form of delusional misidentification?

Tags: abnormal-psychology, reference-request, psychiatry, psychosis

The [delusional misidentification syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delusional_misidentification_syndrome) (DMS) is a condition in which a patient consistently misidentifies persons, places, objects, or events. [Broome (2004)](https://www.academia.edu/167434/The_Rationality_of_Psychosis_and_Understanding_the_Deluded) affirms that:

> The most common form of delusional misidentification is not that of either the exotic Capgras or Fregoli syndromes but delusional misidentification for place... delusional misidentification tends to occur in the context of a patient believing that they are at home or on holiday rather than in hospital and may not necessarily involve close family members or other intimate relationships.

While [Feinberg and Roane (2005)](http://toddfeinberg.com/accelsite/media/mediaFile3100.pdf) claim that:

> The most common form of misidentification is the Capgras syndrome... this disorder consists of the delusional belief that a person or persons have been replaced by ‘‘doubles’’ or imposters.

This seems to be the most widely held opinion. Cf. [David (1997)](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=GnN2nEmpyIMC&lpg=PP1&dq=Essentials%20of%20Postgraduate%20Psychiatry&pg=PA356#v=onepage&q=The%20most%20common%20of%20these%20is%20the%20Capgras%20delusion&f=false).

None of these authors provide a reference (they may be referring to their private clinical experience). Can anyone provide a reference that substantiates or contradicts this claim?